# Date being updated everytime I make change to a product field in django project

Tags: django, django-models

This is my models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):

    type= models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    productid=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fabric=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    bcode=models.CharField(max_length=4)
    Gprice=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have also registered this model in admin successfully. But every time I update the price the added(time added) changes. Please help me with this I want to store the time when the product was added for first time and I dont want to change that.

Comment: Please do check the documentation first. On https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield you can see that auto_now means that the date is set to current for every change saved. You want auto_now_add which only saves date on create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using auto_now=True(auto_now will change the time to the current time whenever you call the save in admin)added=models.DateTimeField. Use(auto_now_add=True) . this wont update the time everytime

Comment: I did this but this is showing error
    added=models.dateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: Sorry figured it out d has to be capital. Thanks for help